# Como validar si hay horarios disponibles para una reunion

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hola tengo que programar una funcion en C# que dados la fechaInicio, FechaFin, SalaDeReuniones valide si se encuentre disponible en ese horario. tengo lo siguiente:

clases modelo:

```
public class Salas
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Ubicacion { get; set; }              
    public ICollection<Reservaciones> Reservaciones { get; set; }        
}
    
 public class Reservaciones
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime Inicio { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime Fin { get; set; }
     public int SalaId { get; set; }
     public string UserId { get; set; }
     public DateTime FechaReservacion { get; set; }    
     public  Salas Sala { get; set; }
 }
```

y tengo la función para validar si se encuentra disponible así:

```
 public bool EsDiponible(Reservaciones nuevaReservacion)
 {
    //obtengo lista de reservaciones del dia
    List<Reservaciones> ListaPorDia = _dbContext.Reservaciones.Where(x => x.Inicio.Day == nuevaReservacion.Inicio.Day && x.SalaId == nuevaReservacion.SalaId).OrderBy(x => x.Inicio).ToList();
    bool inicioDisponible = false;
    bool finDisponible = false;

   //cuando no existen reuniones agendad para el dia retorno true
    if (ListaPorDia.Count == 0)
        return true;


    foreach (var reservacion in ListaPorDia)
    {
        //verifico que la fecha inicio
        if (nuevaReservacion.Inicio >= reservacion.Fin )
        {
            inicioDisponible = true;
           
        }

        if (nuevaReservacion.Fin <= reservacion.Inicio )
        {
            finDisponible = true;
        }

        if (nuevaReservacion.Inicio == reservacion.Inicio && nuevaReservacion.Fin == reservacion.Fin)
        {
            inicioDisponible = false;
            finDisponible = false;
        }
    }

    if (inicioDisponible && finDisponible)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

la función EsDiponible me devuelve false para horarios que si hay disponibilidad pero no logro descifrar cual es la lógica que debo utilizar en las condiciones para validar horarios.

Answer (score 0):

veo algo raro en las condiciones if dentro del bucle. Pones >= lo que (si da el caso que es igual) hace que inicioDisponible sea verdadero, en la siguiente if pones <= que (si da el caso que es igual) hace finDisponible verdadero y en la tercera if también entraría y cumpliría == por lo que inicio y fin ahora son falso. Creo que no esté bien estructurado.

Estás comparando si el inicio de una reserva es mayor o igual que el fin de otra y luego preguntas si el fin de la reserva es menor que el inicio de esa misma, es decir, cosa imposible.

Yo lo haría así con un bucle:

```
public bool EsDiponible(Reservaciones nuevaReservacion)
{
    //obtengo lista de reservaciones del dia
    List<Reservaciones> ListaPorDia = _dbContext.Reservaciones.Where(x => x.Inicio.Day == nuevaReservacion.Inicio.Day && x.SalaId == nuevaReservacion.SalaId).OrderBy(x => x.Inicio).ToList();

    //cuando no existen reuniones agendad para el dia retorno true
    if (ListaPorDia.Count == 0)
        return true;

    for(int i=0; i < ListaPorDia.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Reservaciones reservacion = ListaPorDia[i];
        // Si se cumple esta condición es posible candidato
        if (nuevaReservacion.Inicio >= reservacion.Fin )
        {
            // Si cumple que sólo tenemos una reserva en la lista
            // entonces ya hay hueco pero lanzamos un break para
            // para asegurarnos si nuevaReservacion.Fin no se pasa
            // de la hora máxima establecida para reservaciones.
            if (ListaPorDia.Count == 1) break;

            // Ahora comparo el si el fin de nuestra reservacion
            // es antes del inicio de la reservación siguiente en la lista
            // y si se cumple hemos encontrado un hueco para reservación válido
            if (nuevaReservacion.Fin <= ListaPorDia[i+1].Inicio ) return true;
        }
    }

    // ** Contemplamos la posibilidad que la reservacion pueda ir a continuación
    // ** de la última en la ListaPorDia.
    if (nuevaReservacion.Inicio >= ListaPorDia[ListaPorDia.Count-1].Fin)
    {
        // Aquí tendrías que preguntar si nuevaReservacion.Fin es menor
        // que la hora máxima para reservacion: MAXTIME_PERMITIDO
        return nuevaReservacion.Fin <= MAXTIME_PERMITIDO;
    }

    // Si no encrontró hueco libre para reservacion
    return false;
}
```

Observa que en la condición del bucle he puesto i < ListaPorDia.Count - 1; le resto 1 porque en nuestra condicional preguntaremos por el inicio de la reserva siguiente para ver si hay un hueco entre dos reservas y evitar un error de 'Index Out Of Range'.
Entiendo que es necesario determinar si puedes añadir la reserva al final de la lista de reservas por lo que tendrías que incluir un límite horario para las mismas. Es la condicional que he puesto a continuación del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

**La pregunta es antigua, pero responderé porque acaba de ser actualizada**, en caso de que algún colega tenga dudas sobre planificación de horarios.

El problema radica en que la comprobación de horarios está mal hecha, tanto en la pregunta, como en la respuesta de [Antonio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355172/como-validar-si-hay-horarios-disponibles-para-una-reunion/361644#361644).

**El error está en que la nueva reserva tiene que empezar siempre después del final de todas las reservas** hechas hasta el momento, lo que es incorrecto.

Por ejemplo, hago una reserva de 60min a las 10h, y otra a las 16h. Si ahora hago una reserva a las 12h, no voy a poder porque el inicio de la reserva 12h, no ocurre después del final de la segunda reserva, que es a las 17h. Es decir, **los huecos sin reservar quedan bloqueados para siempre**.

En su lugar, **hay que buscar reservas que choquen con la nueva reserva**. Si encontramos un choque no se puede hacer la reserva, mientras que si no hay choque sí podemos añadir la nueva reserva a la agenda.

Ahora bien, ¿qué consideramos chocar 2 reservas? La respuesta: que se superpongan.

Esto se puede saber si el inicio de una reserva está entre el inicio y fin de la segunda.

```
         Reserva 1             Reserva 1
      ^*************         ^************
       CHOQUE                   CHOQUE
**************          ************************
  Reserva 2                    Reserva 2
```

Nótese que marco en la primera reserva el inicio que me permite detectar el choque.

También se da si el fin de la primera reserva está entre el principio o fin de la segunda.

```
  Reserva 1                Reserva 1
*************^            **********^
       CHOQUE               CHOQUE
      **************    ****************
         Reserva 2         Reserva 2
```

En este caso, marco el fin de la primera reserva, que me permite detectar el choque.

Pero además, hay que añadir dos casos más: que el inicio o el fin de la segunda reserva estén comprendidos entre el inicio y fin de la primera. Es decir, lo mismo que antes, pero desde el punto de vista de la segunda reserva.

Todo esto lo puedo implementar en un método de la propia clase, si dotamos a los objetos de comportamiento propio. O en el caso de un modelo plano (solo estructura), esta lógica se mueve a servicios que manejan este tipo de objetos (las reservas).

```csharp
public class Reserva
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Inicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fin { get; set; }

    // Más propiedades que no vienen al caso

    public bool Choca(Reserva otra)
    {
        return (Inicio >= otra.Inicio && Inicio <= otra.Fin)
            || (Fin >= otra.Inicio && Fin <= otra.Fin)
            || (otra.Inicio >= Inicio && otra.Inicio <= Fin)
            || (otra.Fin >= Inicio && otra.Fin <= Fin);
    }
}
```

El método comprueba solo si una reserva choca con otra, ahora tocaría aplicarlo correctamente a una colección de reservas que comprobamos si chocan contra una nueva reserva, que es constante.

```csharp
public class Sala
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Reserva> Reservas { get; set; }

    // ... Más código

    public bool SePuedeReservar(Reserva nueva)
    {
        var reservasHoy = _dbContext.Reservas
            .Where(r => r.SalaId == nueva.SalaId && r.Inicio.Day == nueva.Inicio.Day)
            .OrderBy(r => r.Inicio)
            .ToList();

        bool choca = reservasHoy.Any(r => r.Choca(nueva));

        return !choca;
    }
}
```

Destacar el cambio de nombres en las clases y variables para mayor legibilidad. Lo único importante es que las clases las he puesto en singular, porque un objeto de la clase solo representa una entidad del mundo real, por lo que no tiene sentido que su nombre sea plural.